# express + mongoose only returns id

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

Model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  passwordConf: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  followedUsers: {
    type: Array,
  },
  avatar: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
  },
});
const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

get-request:

```
app.get('/users', (request, response) => {
  User.find({}, 'handle users', function (error, users) {
    if (error) console.log(error);
    response.send({
      users: users
    })
  })
});
```

When I run this im only getting the `_id`'s back:

```
{
  users: [{
      _id: "5c097129f3c87328ff608c0d"
    },
    {
      _id: "5c097140f3c87328ff608c0e"
    },
    {
      _id: "5c0a1b17c1613117d41d8846"
    },
    {
      _id: "5c0a1b90c9ecbc17f3c7b98f"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I look into my mongodb erverything is there. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 'handle' and 'users' properties are not defined in the schema. Why are you using it? Reference:https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find

Comment: thanks @abskmj ! I'm an Idiot! I copied the schema and didn't change that. That was my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write code like this

```
app.get('/users', (request, response) => {
  User.find({}, function (error, users) {
    if (error) console.log(error);
    response.send({
      users: users
    })
  })
});
```

or for particular fields

```
enter code here
app.get('/users', (request, response) => {
      User.find({}, 'email name', function (error, users) {
        if (error) console.log(error);
        response.send({
          users: users
        })
      })
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @abskmj

get-request need to look like this:

```
app.get('/users', (request, response) => {
  User.find({}, 'email username password passwordConf followedUsers avatar', function (error, users) {
    if (error) console.log(error);
    response.send({
      users: users
    })
  })
});
```